# Resize table view cell

Tags: uitableview, autolayout

I have this image url .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pdYs.jpg

It is a table view with json data .i want ,when there is no image present in the the table view cell will be auto resized. that means - when there is no image the description lable will take place of the image view . Please someone help me how to do this .Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add all elements to Vertical Stack View and hide imageView when no image present.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: I have another question. could you please help me ?                                              questions  - I want to go from one view (Created programmettically) to another view(created using storyboard). How to archive this ?